# implictly typed local variable 'var' to an explicitly typed local variable

Tags: c#, var, implicit

Say i have a rather convoluted expression, using this expression as an example, and i want to replace the var with an explicit variable?

```
var collection = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
   .Where(x => x % 2 != 0)
   .Reverse()
   .Select(x => new { 
                       original = x, 
                       sqrt = Math.Sqrt(x) 
                    });
```

I've tried quite a few combinations to replace the var, but it wont it just keeps giving me an error. Oh and as for VS telling me the type it hasn't really helped...

E.g. I've tried replacing

```
var collection
```

with

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, double>> collection
```

Comment: *`Dictionary<int, double> collection = 
                                        Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                                                .Where(x => x % 2 != 0)
                                                .Reverse()
                                                .ToDictionary(x => x, x => Math.Sqrt(x));`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really really want to put something there, you can use

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> collection = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(x => x % 2 != 0)
      .Reverse()
      .Select(x => new { original = x, sqrt = Math.Sqrt(x) });
```

You can't do much more than that, since you are creating an anonymous object in your expression.

*Please read the comments made by Jeppe Stig Nielsen for a detailed explanation about why you shouldn't do this even though you can.*

Comment: You could use `IEnumerable<dynamic>` to access the properties later on. With `object` you can't do much (e.g. no further projections). But generally it would be better to create a concrete type here and project to that class instead of anonymous type

Comment: Yea, you are right, that was the drawback of using object :) I corrected the answer, but yea, I agree creating a new class would make things easier to understand.

Comment: While this is possible, there's only disadvantages to it. You lose type safety, for example `collection.First().asdf();` compiles. And you lose performance, because binding (resolution of members like overloads) will need to take place at run-time. However, if you need to `return` the `collection`, you might consider something like this, because the method return type cannot be `var`. However in that case it is much better to use a type-safe named type like `KeyValuePair<int, double>` or `Tuple<int, double>`.

Comment: I never said this is nice or should be done (and in both cases my personal answer is no); He asked if he could, and I just answered how. I can only agree with you on all you said.

Comment: Also, this only works because `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant in `T`. Suppose you wanted a `List<>` instead. You would append `.ToList()` after the `Select(...)`. Now you couldn't use `List<dynamic>` in that case! Please do use `var` when anonymous types are involved. You do know what the strong type is, but you just don't care to come up with a name for that type.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're selecting a `new` object, the result is an [Anonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx), and with those you can't substitute the type for the var.

Comment: So far everything i've read states that you should only use var so long as you know the type; would this then be an exception to the rule?

Comment: @DraconianTimes It is a matter of taste to some point whether to use `var` or not (I use it wherever I can in locals). Here, however, the actual type *has no name* yet ("anonymous type") in uncompiled code and therefore *cannot be named fully*.

Comment: @DraconianTimes I don't know where you've read that; if you *cannot* know the type (because it is an anonymous type, or something *involving* an anonymous type), then you can't use anything *except* `var`. If you *do* know the type: just use whatever is clearest.

Comment: @DraconianTimes Where did you read that? Well, you do know the type. It is *the* anonymous type with two properties, the first called `original` and having type `int`, and the second called `sqrt` with type `double`. This type is anonymous and that means it has no name. Therefore do use `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you maybe want something like this

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, double>> collection = 
        Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                  .Where(x => x%2 != 0)
                  .Reverse()
                  .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, double> (x,Math.Sqrt(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way is to turn your anonymous type into an explicitly declared class:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<WithRoot> collection = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
       .Where(x => x % 2 != 0)
       .Reverse()
       .Select(x => new WithRoot(x, Math.Sqrt(x)));    
}

private sealed class WithRoot
{
    public WithRoot(int orig, double root)
    {
        this.Original = orig;
        this.SquareRoot = root;
    }

    public int Original { get; private set; }

    public double SquareRoot { get; private set; }
}
```

This enables you to name the type in code, while maintaining the *full type-safety* (in contrast to solutions with `dynamic` or `object`). However, it makes your code much more verbose. Frankly I doubt that you need that and I discourage you from doing that just for the sake of explicit typing. `var` is not bad/evil.

**Functional Difference:** Note that `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are *not overwritten* in my code sample. This happens automatically as well when you use an anonymous type.

Comment: Using a class would also allow the result to be stored in a field or passed to a method - then again using a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, double>>` would do that as well.